# Why my password hash is returning false when i provide the correct password?

Tags: php, sql, hash, passwords

when i hash my password, i used password_hash($password, PASSWORD_ARGON2I).

Now i wan to verify my login password against the hash password stored in my sql server. However, the password_verify keep returning false even though i provided the correct password. Can anyone help?

I have tried searching on google and stackoverflow for solution but to no avail

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $username = strip_tags(trim($_POST["username"]));
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM USERNAME WHERE user_id= '".$username."' ";
    $params = array();
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

    $hash_password = $row['password'];

    $new = password_verify($password, $hash_password);


    if(var_dump(password_verify($password, $hash_password))){

        $msg = "Login Success"; 

    }else{

        $msg = "Login failure";

    }

    echo $msg;
}
```

Output returns "Login Failure"

Comment: Get rid of the `var_dump()`, should be `if(password_verify($password, $hash_password)){`

Comment: @RiggsFolly doesn't work. i tried

Comment: Also stop fiddling with the `$_POST["username"]` and chnage the SQL to use a prepared parameterised and bound query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Messing with input is dangerous, you may be effecting the content of `userid` by using strip_tags and its unnecessary anyway if you use prepared queries.
2. using `var_dump()` in this line `if(var_dump(password_verify($password, $hash_password))){` will cause a false all the time as `var_dump()` returns NULL.
3. It is also a good idea to add some error checking to the `sqlsrv_` calls.

So suggested code amendments

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    //$username = strip_tags(trim($_POST["username"]));
    //$password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM USERNAME WHERE user_id= ?";
    $params = array($_POST["username"]);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params);
    if( !$stmt ) {
        print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }

    if( sqlsrv_execute( $stmt ) === false ) {
        print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }

    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

    //$hash_password = $row['password'];
    //$new = password_verify($password, $hash_password);
    //if(password_verify($password, $hash_password)){

    if(password_verify($_POST["username"], $row['password']))){
        $msg = "Login Success"; 
    }else{
        $msg = "Login failure";
    }
    echo $msg;
}
```

> Of course the other thing to check is that the hashing of the password worked correctly, ass if that failed you will never get the verify to work.

Answer (score 0):

var_dump() always returns "void".
password_verify() returns "bool". So you have to check for password_verify() directly.

! WARNNING !

Your code is open to SQL-Injections! I would not recommend to use your code.
However, since you asked for the one thing in particular, this might work:

```
if(password_verify($password, $hash_password)){
    $msg = "Login Success"; 
} else {
    $msg = "Login failure";
}
```

Comment: I found what's the problem. The data type i used for password column is nvarchar(300). When i changed it to nvarchar(MAX). it finally works!!!

Comment: thanks for bringing this up. Can you enlighten how can iimprove my code to prevent SQL injection? FYI my application is connected to SQL Server, not mysql database.

Comment: SQL injection is not a mysql exclusive thing. Every database that uses some kind of sql dialect can be affected by it. You should use prepared statements to prevent most of the possible attacks.

Answer (score 0):

In addressing to RiggsFolly SQL injection concern, i have redo my code as shown below. Hope this is the right way.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM USERNAME WHERE user_id= ? ";
    $params = array($username);
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params);

    if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){

        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

        $hash_password = $row['password'];

        $new = password_verify($password, $hash_password);

        if(password_verify($password, $hash_password)){

            $msg = "Login Success"; 

        }else{

            $msg = "Login failure";

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Roughly what I suggested in my answer